# Previously detached view to have multiple detached views together {Programmatically not possible}

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

So, I have block of code which will detach the view and will open it in a separate window. But I have a for loop which will detach several view all into its own separate window. But my issue is that I want to add all those detached windows into one window together as we can do that with dragging and dropping in eclipse. Is that possible Programmatically? Is there an API that I can use?
Below is the code:

```
for (DetachedFolder detachedFolder : detachedFolders)
    {
     for (int k = 0; k < detachedFolder.detachedFolderViewIds.size(); k++)
        {
            IViewReference ref = page.findViewReference(
                    detachedFolder.detachedFolderViewIds.get(k),
                    PerspectiveUtil.getPatientViewSecondaryId());
            ViewPane pane = (ViewPane) ((WorkbenchPartReference) ref).getPane();
            LayoutPart part = (LayoutPart) pane.getContainer();
            part.setBounds(detachedFolder.detachedFolderBounds);
            pane.getPage().getActivePerspective().getPresentation().detachPart(ref); 
            pane.flushLayout();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Several of the classes you are using here are **internal** so you are violating the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) by using them. Further some of them don't exist at all in Eclipse 4 so you will have major problems if you move to Eclipse 4 (even in 3.x compatibility mode).

Comment: I know I am relying on internal API's, that's why I want to know if there is any other way, which I can implement to create a Detachedwindow and then keep all of them together.

Comment: In Eclipse 4 you would use the application model and the model service, but that doesn't exist in Eclipse 3. I'm not sure if Eclipse 3 had any proper APIs for this.